# What does abstract mean in this context?

Tags: python, abstract

I need some help in understanding a python concept.

```
class TilePuzzleProblem(search.Problem):
""" This class is the class for the NxN - blanks tile puzzle problem """

    def __init__(self, N, blanks, initial, goal):
        """ Initialize """
        search.Problem.__init__(self, initial, goal)
        self.N = N
        self.blanks = blanks

    def successor(self, state):
        """ Generate the successors of the given state. Returns a list of (move, successor) pairs"""
        abstract

    def h(self, node):
        abstract
```

Currently the code hangs at the `abstract` part of the function `h(...)`, but I have no idea what `abstract` means, hence can not understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a trick described [here](http://norvig.com/python-iaq.html). There's not keyword `abstract` in Python, so, if you won't override this method in some subclass, it'll cause `NotImplementedError`.

Comment: `NameError`, actually.  I think this trick may be the single worst idea I've seen all week.

Comment: Yes, terrible way of doing it. You should actually raise `NotImplementedError` yourself in the methods that need overriding.

Comment: This makes me a sad (programming) panda.

Comment: Also, don't be confused that Stack Overflow highlights `abstract` as if it were a keyword.  The system that SO uses has to accommodate multiple programming languages, and in many `abstract` _is_ a keyword.  But not in Python.

Answer (score 5):

An abstract method is one which a class doesn't implement, making it an abstract class; subclasses must override all abstract methods (i.e., provide concrete implementations) to be concrete classes, i.e., ones for which you can make instances.  The normal way in Python to express "this method is abstract" is to have the method's body be `raise NotImplementedError`.

For more about the general concept, apart from its specifics in Python, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type).

So, formally, you need to subclass this and implement those two methods marked as "abstract". (Depending on your TA's hints, he or she may actually mean that you should replace the word "abstract" with a working body of code, but that would be quite a stretch with respect the normal meaning of "abstract" in OOP!-).

Answer (score 1):

An abstract function is a function with no implementation.  It's a placeholder, just there to fill out the class contract so that you know what methods subclass should provide.  What you need to do here is create a descendant of `TilePuzzleProblem` and fill in your own implementation of `h`.  If you want to run it as is, create a descendant and make your `h` do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract means the class must be inherited.  Abstract or "base" classes are there to provide a base type which you can extend through inheritance.  You cannot instantiate an abstract class, only the classes that inherit it.

See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_science%29#Abstract_classes) for more information.

One reason you'd want to use an abstract base class is if you want to categorize or group your sub-types.  For example, `Car`, `Truck` and `Plane` would all inherit from the `Vehicle` abstract base class.  You can't just instantiate a "vehicle", you have to instantiate a car, truck or plane.  Being abstract protects it from being instantiated.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!
why would someone use an abstract class? i'm trying to understand the reason for it's existance...

Comment: ... and in the OP's example code, the `abstract` is simply a marker for people looking at it, that here is something missing (the real implementation).

Comment: also, can there be abstract functions?

Comment: Why you'd want to use abstract classes:  imagine a Shape class.  Some possible methods would be GetArea, GetPerimeter, etc.  However, unless you know what kind of shape you're dealing with, implementing these are impossible.  Thus, they'd be abstract in the base Shape class, and be implemented in the subclasses (Rectangle, Triangle, etc).  Look at the wikipedia entry on OOP.

Comment: In Python2.6 there are many abstract base classes (ABCs) in module collections, for example `collections.MutableSet` -- the ABC defines many specific set operations, but you must subclass and implement the primitives for the set's internal storage yourself.

Comment: abstract function does not really make sense, as they are not inherited and overridden, but you could interpret as static methods on a class? Or an abstract function in a module, where you have to "subclass" the module itself (by composition or somehow).